# Why is array_combine not returning an array?

Tags: php, arrays

When I try to print the array returned from this function, I get a blank screen.

My array `$terms` and `$definitions` are both the same length and they exist before and after  I call `make_associative_array()`.

```
function make_associative_array() {
    return array_combine($terms, $definitions);
}

$c = make_associative_array();
print_r($c);
```

$terms:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Nock (verb) [1] => End [2] => Serving [3] => Nock (noun) 
)
```

$definitions:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => To place an arrow against the string prior to shooting. [1] => A group of arrows shot during a tournament. Usually 6. [2] => Thread wound around a bow string to protect the string. [3] => A notch at the rear of an arrow. The bow string is placed in the nock. 
)
```

I am using PHP 5.6.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case - `array_combine` returns `NULL` because both `$terms` & `$definitions` are null inside the scope of `make_associative_array`.

You can either make them global:

```
function make_associative_array() {
    global $terms, $definitions;
    return array_combine($terms, $definitions);
}
```

Or pass them to the function:

```
function make_associative_array($terms, $definitions) {
    return array_combine($terms, $definitions);
}
$c = make_associative_array($terms, $definitions);
```

Anyway - I really advise you to turn on errors:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40cfd2d197aebd4d935c793c1ea662cab50ce8b1

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass parameter to function

```
 <?php
    function make_associative_array($terms,$definitions) {

        return array_combine($terms, $definitions);
    }

    $terms=Array ( 0 => 'Nock (verb)', 1 => 'End', 2=> 'Serving', 3=> 'Nock (noun) '
    );

    $definitions=Array ( 
         0 => 'To place an arrow against the string prior to shooting.' ,1 => 'A group of arrows shot during a tournament. Usually 6.', 2 => 'Thread wound around a bow string to protect the string.' ,3=> 'A notch at the rear of an arrow. The bow string is placed in the nock.' 
    );

    $c = make_associative_array($terms,$definitions);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($c);
```

output will be

```
Array
(
    [Nock (verb)] => To place an arrow against the string prior to shooting.
    [End] => A group of arrows shot during a tournament. Usually 6.
    [Serving] => Thread wound around a bow string to protect the string.
    [Nock (noun) ] => A notch at the rear of an arrow. The bow string is placed in the nock.
)
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat an answer that already exists (you can just vote the existing answer, you know...)

Comment: @Dekel. i have not repeated answer .i given answer by executing hist code in localhost.if we exicute in localhost and while posting it will take time it will take time when we post

Comment: Your answer is exactly the one I already wrote. can you explain the differences?

Comment: @Dekel.sorry .i  dont want argue .sorry. i have updated his array string and exicuted and given output. i have not asked op to accept or vote my answer its his interest.

Comment: That's not the issue here... and it's not about arguing. If an answer already exists there is not reason to repeat it. If you think your answer is different - just say how exactly it is.

Comment: @Dekel.what is your issue brother. i dont know why you are arguing.Its my wish to post my answer i have not copied your answer  or written same like your answer. There is no rule in stack that ou cant post any answer if answer is same . i told you i have posted answer by typing in localhost and when we type answer page will open but you are good in php so you posted before me.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, I'm just trying to understand what post an answer that already exists. thats all.